# Browser Back Button Shows Blank Page (Create React App + React Router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm using Create React App and React Router. When I click a link on page 1 such as , it will navigate to page 2 successfully. But then when I click the back button in Chrome, it shows a blank page. Inspecting in the console shows that CRA's default index.html page is loaded, but it never gets to rendering the . In case it helps, after clicking the back button, the URL shown in the browser is correct.

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to remedy the issue.

Here is the line in my index.js file that renders the . I believe this is standard in any CRA app.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the a tag that I click from page1 to go to page2:

```
<a className={props.className} href={"/page2"}>
{props.children}
</a>
```

The index.html which is rendered when I click the Chrome browser back button from page2 is the index.html autogenerated by CRA: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app, which is essentially just a blank page.

The problem is that `<App />` never actually gets rendered after performing the back operation (despite it being in index.js).

I'm using React router, which is located inside the `<App />` component.

Here is how my App component is defined:

```
const App = () => {
return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path={
                "/page1"
              }
              render={(props) => {
                return <Page1 {...props} />;
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path={
                "/page2"
              }
              render={(props) => {
                return <Page2 {...props} />;
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/*"
              render={(props) => (
                <ErrorPage error={ErrorType.NOT_FOUND_ERROR} />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    };
```

Comment: This is not enough infos to help really. What Router are you using? What server? Please share some code

Comment: Just edited the question with more details. Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Can you show how you have defined your routes?

Comment: Just updated the answer to show how routes are defined! The problem is that even when I console.log at the top of the <App /> component, it doesn't get there after the back button is pressed.